# Ограничена ли многомерность массива?

Tags: java, массивы

Вот объявляется переменная двумерного массива `mas[][]`:

```
int mas[][] = new int[2][3];
```

Ограничен ли массив неким количеством "мерностей" (`[]`) как-то лексически, или упирается ли в возможности памяти/машины?

```
int mas[][]...? = new int[2][3]...?;
```

Comment: В данном случае вы резервируете память массива и явный размер каждого его уровня.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, ограничена. Максимум – 255.

[JVM specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1):

> An array type descriptor is valid only if it represents 255 or fewer dimensions.